# Do I have to buy Minecraft again to make a new account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been using my brother's account to play Minecraft and already have it downloaded on my laptop. However I want to create and use my own account do I have to re buy the game

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

You pay for the minecraft login, not for the downloaded `.exe` file. Anyone can download the minecraft launcher for free.

If you want to change you name, you can do that - rather than buy a new account.